# Dataframe pandas how to pass list as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists, such as:

```
list_columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','k','l','m','n']
```

and a list of values

```
list_values = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100, 111, 222]
```

I want to create a Pandas dataframe using list_columns as **columns**.

I tried with `df = pd.DataFrame(list_values, columns=list_columns)`
but it doesn't work

I get this error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 12), indices imply (12, 12)`

Comment: What do you mean `list_values` as columns? Please be more specific about the expected output.

Comment: list_columns as columns. I've just edited it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A dataframe is a two-dimensional object. To reflect this, you need to feed a nested list. Each sublist, in this case the *only* sublist, represents a row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list_values], columns=list_columns)

print(df)

#     a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   k    l    m    n
# 0  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
```

If you supply an index with length greater than 1, Pandas broadcasts for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list_values], columns=list_columns, index=[0, 1, 2])

print(df)

#     a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   k    l    m    n
# 0  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
# 1  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
# 2  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly just wrap list_values in brackets so it's a list of lists

```
list_columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','k','l','m','n']
list_values = [[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100, 111, 222]]

pd.DataFrame(list_values, columns=list_columns)
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   k    l    m    n
0  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
```

Answer (score 2):

from your list you can do like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_values) 
df=df.T
df.columns=list_columns
>>df

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   k    l    m    n
0  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  100  111  222
```